# Class initialization sequence

Tags: c++, constructor

Say, I have 2 classes:

```
class A
{
  A(int address) : addr(address), B_instance(this);

  int addr;
  struct adata _adata;
  B B_instance;
}

class B
{
  B(A * _top) : top(_top) { };

  struct bdata _bdata;
  A * top;
}
```

Now I want to add more data to A::A, for it to be written into member structure and distributed further to B::B, but(!) after being processed a bit in A::A. How can I rewrite classes to achieve that?

If I just do

```
A(int address, void * somedata) : addr(address)
{
  // Some data processing
  B_instance::B(this, newdata);
}
```

then I'd have to write default constructor for B to call it before main constructor (ugly). If I make a member of B, that just receives processed data in the end of A::A, then it would be ugly too, I guess. Are there better options?

Comment: Calling  `B_instance::B(this, newdata);` in the constructor body won't work anyway. Can't you write a specific function to do what you need? (you can call functions in the constructor initializer list also).

Comment: So you need to process the data when instanciating class `A`, before calling `B::constructor()`?

Comment: @user0042, what do you mean? Like, construct classes first, and then call A::Init(), that processes data and calls B::Init()?

Comment: You can change the B_instance to be std::unique_ptr<B> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr. This will allow to initialize the member when you have enough data to call the constructor of B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a data member, `B_instance` will be always initialized before entering the constructor's body. You can add a (static) member function to return the necessary data, and use it in the member initializer list. e.g.

```
class A
{
private:
  static void* getNewData() { 
    // Some data processing 
    return ...;
  }
public:
  A(int address) : addr(address), B_instance(this, getNewData()) {}

  int addr;
  struct adata _adata;
  B B_instance;
};
```